# Apache CXF - startup time

Tags: spring, cxf

We are working on one of the application wherein Apache CXF, Spring is used to develop webservices. The application now contains more than 50 webservices and more than 300 spring managed beans. Every time the application server is started it takes more than 15-20 minutes. (server with 4gb ram, jboss/tomcat app server, linux os)
Is there any way to reduce the startup time taken by the server.

Comment: Yes. Plug in in a profiler and find out what's slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely plug in a profiler and figure out what is going on.   That seems WAY WAY longer than it should.

My gut feeling is that it's trying to hit the internet or something for schemas and then waiting for timeouts and such.   That's the normal cause for that level of slowdown.   In addition to a profiler, using Wireshark or something to monitor and outbound traffic would also be a good idea.    If that IS the case, then using a catalog to redirect any traffic to local copies of schemas and wsdl's would produce a HUGE benefit.